# Menu to navigate through sheets doesn't work proper

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a menu to navigate through sheets. But when I use one of the buttons to go to another sheet and type something in this another sheet the things that I type appear in the first one. Although when I use the tabs to jump to one sheet to another it works fine. Seems to be that the macro is considering a relative reference instead a absolute one.

Here's what my macro does (or at least should):

```
Private Sub cadastrar_clientes_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Menu.Hide
    Sheets("Clientes").Select
    Range("A1048576").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```

Notes:

I've tried to use ".activate" instead of ".select".
I've tried to use only "Sheets("Clientes").Select", even so the bug occurs.
To execute "Excel /unregserver" on the Windows CMD solved my problem once, but I couldn't do this again. It doesn't seems to work anymore.
I did a menu like this one once, but I didn't had these problems.

When the workbook opens the following code is executed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End Sub
```

That's it. I hope that somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all code on VBA module Menu with this (tested in the file you provided)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub fechar_menu_Click()
    Menu.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub novo_pedido_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Novo pedido"), "B5"
End Sub
Private Sub ver_pedidos_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consultar pedido"), "F1"
End Sub
Private Sub cadastrar_clientes_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Clientes")
End Sub
Private Sub cadastrar_produtos_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Produtos")
End Sub
Private Sub cadastrar_transportadoras_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Transportadoras")
End Sub
Private Sub painel_financeiro_Click()
    goToTab ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Painel Financeiro"), "B3"
End Sub

Private Sub goToTab(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional cel As String = vbNullString)
    Menu.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        .Activate
        If Len(cel) = 0 Then
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            .Range(cel).Select
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, it seems that your last sugestion is good but it doesn't run like it should (at least I couldn't figure it out). The bug goes on. Well, here's the file: http://bit.ly/1WrEgcu. You can start at the "Novo pedido" sheet. From there hit the "Menu" button and go to "Cadastrar clientes" using the button with the same name. Once you're there type something and you'll seet that the typed text appears  in the "Novo pedido" sheet instead of in the "Clientes" sheet. The code that I posted upthere is in a form called "menu".

Comment: The latest update works with your file. If this solves the initial issue please accept the answer as a reference for others (click the check mark on the left and upvote it if you found it useful)

Comment: It must be something going on my computer then. I'll try in another. I still have the same bug here. The point of using a menu is not to use the tabs to move from a sheet to another, when I use them all works good, but even using your code I have the same problem. I'll run some tests here. Anyway, thanks a lot dude.

Comment: I didn't see the last update. This last big one. I'll try it now. Thanks.

Comment: Well. Still not working. I'm starting to feel dumb. Here's a video so you can picture what's going on: http://bit.ly/1h0JCeL.

Comment: So, I tried it on my girlfriend's laptop and it works there. Thanks Paul. But... I still have to figure it out. I hate these kind of bugs. If you have any hint about what's going on keep me updated, please. I haven't chaged anything. I'll check it anyway.

Comment: Try closing Excel: open Task Manager go to Processes and make sure you stop all Exce.exe processes (did you change any other Excel settings?)

Comment: I did it. I also restarted the computer. For a moment the problem doesn't occur, but in a moment it happens again. Here's the thing: When I run the comand "Excel /unregserver" and then "Excel /regserver" in the CMD the bug goes away. But it doesn't prevent it to happen again. Does someone understand why?

Comment: Ok, so now we know the problem is not from within Excel or VBA, but some setting is changed in the environment (I think you're using Windows 10?) I'm not sure how your version of Office integrates with the new OS as I'm still on Win 7 with Excel 2010

Comment: I don't know for sure if the problem is with the OS, I have to run more tests. But, anyway, you've saved me from a lot of work make me understanding better the problem. I'll make this thread as answered, should I?

Comment: I think there is an improvement in the code: I'll update the question to include the full module so that others can see how to reduce code, and then you can mark it as answered (and we've confirmed it works on 2 other computers, although probably the previous code worked as well bat at least now it's streamlined). I'm still thinking what else can cause this but I don't have much to work with...

Comment: You updated the file on dropbox and I don't have the old version of the code; but this makes me think - how are you running the file on your machine, and what version of Excel is on the 2nd computer? (did you have to download the file)

Comment: I update the answer to try something else on your machine: changed all calls from `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(...` to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(...` - this might help

Comment: I've used the same version of Office and Windows on both cases. Maybe it's a problem with Dropbox. I had some issues with it when I was writing some HTML codes once. I'll try to make a copy of the file and place it out of the Dropbox folder. - Nop, it wasn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I know a lot more about the problem now. I've tested the workbook over various computers and came to the conclusion that the problem is within the Office 2013. I haven't seem this issue when running the 2007 or 2010 version. So far I haven't come to a solution. I would like to thanks Paul Bika for helping.